# Reverse the max-min normalization of Beta/Gamma-distributed data

Tags: normalization, gamma-distribution, beta-distribution

I normalized my data using max-min normalization as follows
$$X_{normed}=\frac{X-\min(X)}{\max(X)-\min(X)}$$

How can I find the distribution of $X$ given the distribution of $X_{normed}$, if

1. $X_{normed} \sim Gamma(\alpha,\beta)$ where $\alpha,\beta$ repectively denote the shape and rate parameter.
2. $X_{normed} \sim Beta(\alpha,\beta)$ where $\alpha,\beta$ denote the shape parameters.

Comment: Your renormalised data is over $(0,1)$ while the Gamma distribution is over $(0,\infty)$...

Comment: Given that you normed variable is bounded to the unit interval, wouldn't a beta distribution make more sense? (That would also make reversing it quite straightforward.)

Comment: @Glen_b: That makes sense, so I edited my question. But I still don't get how reversing is "straightforward" in the case of Beta distribution? Also, one more issue: what if I have new data, saying, $X_i>\max(X)$. If I normalize it using the formula in the post, $X_{normed}>1$ so it can't be fitted into the Beta distribution...

Comment: If $X\sim B(\alpha,\beta)$, then $1-X\sim B(\beta , \alpha)$. The other issue is a problem with you choice of norm. I believe a couple of questions on site touch on that issue. Note that the problem exists  on both sides, not just to the right

Comment: I'm really sorry, but I still can't relate how $1-X_{normed} \sim B(\beta,\alpha)$ is useful for the derivation of the distribution of $X$ here? It just implies $\frac{max(X)-X}{max(X)-min(X)} \sim B(\beta,\alpha)$.

Comment: Ah, I see. I was interpreting 'reverse' in a sense different from the one you intended, my apologies.

Comment: Sorry for my bad English... But if $max(X)$ and $min(X)$ are known, let's say, $A$ and $B$, is there any to know the distribution of $X$?